# The relevant issues of OAuth automatic login in Vue 3 project?

Tags: vuejs3

**Implementation**

Automatically redirect to OAuth connection for authorization when the WeChat Work client is opened, and exchange the Callback Code returned to the backend for the user token for automatic login. If it's not the WeChat Work client, redirect to the Login page.

**Issues**

Currently, I've written the entire logic in router.beforeEach. Is it appropriate to write it here? Where does everyone else write it (e.g., should the redirection and automatic login be written in main.ts before routing)?

Is the workflow problematic? My basic logic is: check if there is a token to determine if the user is logged in > check if it's the WeChat Work client (if so, redirect to OAuth connection and callback) > check if there is a Code carried, then automatically log in.

```
if (!userStore.token) {
    if (isWeWork()) {
      userStore.loginWeWork().then(isSuccess => {
        if (isSuccess) next();
      });
    } else {
      next({ path: LOGIN_URL, replace: true });
    }
  } else {
    useCachedViewStoreHook().addCachedView(to);
    next();
  }

// loginWeWork
async loginWeWork() {
      const workCode = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("code");
      if (!workCode) {
        window.location.href = getOAuthUrl();
        return;
      }

      try {

        const { data }: any = await loginWeWorkApi({ code: workCode });

        this.setToken(data.token);
        this.setUserInfo(data.userInfo);
        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        return false;
      }
    }
```